# How to intercept the application update event in obj-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, events

Is it possible to intercept the update of applications for statistics in `Objective-C` as it is done in `Java` (UpgradeBroadcastReceiver)?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve? Do you just want to know when your app has been updated via the App Store?

Comment: Yes, I need to track the app update as an event for my analytics

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no specific event that is triggered when an app is updated.

However, when an app is updated, this guarantees that the app will be launched from a cold state. In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` do a check on your version and/or build number and save it somewhere (such as `NSUserDefaults`). If the number is different than what you already had stored, then you know the app has been updated and you can react accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, if I do not find a better option, I will do it